# Run Python Code on SSH Target using Airflow

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

There are 2 systems: `A` and `B`. Airflow Scheduler, webserver, redis and flower runs on `A` while an Airflow worker runs on `B`. Both systems are running Ubuntu 18.04 and uses Airflow 1.10.10 in docker containers.

Is it possible to create a DAG that remotely runs Python code (defined in that DAG) on `B`?

`SSHOperator` allows the remote execution of a bash command on `B` over SSH, but we require a remote execution of Python code over SSH instead.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've gotten your answer already, but I had a very similar (if not the very same) problem until just a few moments ago and thought I could provide the answer here.
The easiest way is to mount a shared folder onto both nodes so they can both access the actual physical DAG files.
More details about my case can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/24275).